# Then that or then that of

Tags: grammaticality

> The saddest part is that notwithstanding the government’s grand
>   announcement — increasing the number of workdays to 150 in the nine
>   drought-affected states — all these states have a negative cash
>   balance. **It’s hardly surprising then that only 5 per cent households**
>   have completed 150 days of work. This is conclusive proof that the
>   government is ignoring the two most important legal requirements of
>   the MGNREGA — work on demand, and full and timely payment of wages.

In this article they used `then that only 5%`. Is it correct or should it be `than that of`?

Comment: 'then' is an adverb meaning "in that case". You could remove it completely, or put it between commas... "It's hardly surprising, then, that..."

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing *then* here with *than*.
To understand this better you can write the sentence as:

> It’s hardly surprising then, that only 5 per cent households have completed 150 days of work.

Comment: Agreed.  You could read it as being like "therefore" - "It's hardly surprising, therefore, that only 5 per cent of households..."